# QGIS atlas print composer : aggregate (bigger overlap)

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, print-composer, aggregate, qgis-expression

With QGIS 3.30, In the composer interface, I generate an atlas. My iteration layer is polygonal layer (platforms). I added a text element to automatically get by spatial intersection the 'parcel_id' attribute present in another polygonal layer. I use the aggregate function for this task :

```sql
aggregate(
    'LAYER':='PARCEL_LAYER',
    aggregate:='concatenate',
    expression:="parcel_id",
    filter:=intersects(geometry(@parent), $geometry)
)
```

It works. But the result shows values of all the intersections. I would like it limit to the result of the biggest intersection. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`overlay_intersect()` function](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#overlay-intersects) for that. In newer QGIS versions, it has an optional argument `sort_by_intersection_size`. So this should work:

```
concatenate( 
overlay_intersects(
        'PARCEL_LAYER',
        "parcel_id",
        sort_by_intersection_size:='des'
    )[0]
)
```